# Buffered image not finding file

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to create a resized buffered image from a file.  Originally I was just reading in the file as type `Image`.  I would like to resize it, so I've started trying to use `BufferedImage`.  Reading a file into the `Image` type worked great, but now it throws an exception when reading.  Here is the code.

```
BufferedImage origImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg"));
            int type = origImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : origImage.getType();
            image = super.resizeImage(origImage, type);
```

Here is the code that worked:

```
image = (new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg"))).getImage();
```

In the first case, image is a BufferedImage.  In the second it is just an image.  The code throws an exception when reading the file(the first line) but I've tried absolute path also.  So, dunno.

Comment: I think the path to image is wrong and I would also try to rename image to DoorVase.jpg. I suppose this jpg is included in project? What is the absolute path to image?

Comment: I agree, but why would it work with the bottom set of code?  One sec for abs path.

Comment: check is your file really exist in given location, remeber `/` means root folder

Comment: You don't need the leading slash on your file path.

Comment: Ok thanks Quirliom.  Ok, everyone commenting must realize that the image will display when I use the bottom set of code.  Image = ...   Why would one filepath work and not another?  Is there anything wrong with the code itself?  Could it be ImageIO?

Comment: at so a lot of examples for working with resources, I think this question is duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that worked used `getClass().getResource("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg"))`, but the code that doesn't uses `new File("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg")`.

Instead you should be using `getClass().getResource("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg"))`, for example...

```
BufferedImage origImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/Door&Vase.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thank you, so easy to see now.  It's in resources, get the resource. Durr.